# Creating a swimlane report, resource names on left hand side, with dates along the top

Tags: jira, project-management

Given a list of jira tickets, with fields such as this:
[example list of fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HLMa.png)
Is it possible to create a report that will automatically render these jiras by team member name on the side and date on the top? The aim is to show what each person is working on, week by week.

Eg. it would look something like this:
[example swimlane diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ogYP.png)

Or do I need to buy a plugin to do this?
thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about project management, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with plain Jira.

Few options:

1. $$$ - With [Mail.Ru Calendar plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211040/mail-ru-calendar?hosting=server&tab=overview) you can have a "sort" of result similar to what you need by:

   - selecting week view
   - use a filter to pick selected issues
2. $$$ - With [EazyBi](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211051/eazybi-reports-and-charts-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview) you can have exactly what you want, but you need a little practising with MDX language or interface.
3. FREE - You may try with the new [Analytics & BI for JQL](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215775/analytics-bi-for-jql?hosting=server&tab=overview) but I've never tried

If these are not good for you, just spend some time on the Jira marketplace, there are MANY reporting plugins.

Comment: Many thanks (waiting for my reputation to increase so i can upvote)

Comment: sorry, i anyone has an example of one of the plugins on the atlassian site that do this, that would be great - i can see there are a lot of options, but as i don't have a version of jira that i can download these onto and try them out, i can't tell if they do what i want.

Comment: Just click on the links of the answer to see screenshots and documentation of the plugins. Some will provide a demo site.

To accept an answer to a question you made, you don't need reputation.